# Filter rows based on multiple string columns in R

Tags: r

Given a dataframe as follows:

```
  city type  count
0   bj    a     10
1   bj    a     23
2   bj    b     12
3   bj    c     34
4   sh    a     17
5   sh    b     18
6   sh    c     25
7   sh    c     13
8   sh    a     12
```

I want to filter rows based on `city` and `type`: `bj-a, bj-c, sh-b`, the expected result will like this:

```
  city type  count
0   bj    a     10
1   bj    a     23
2   bj    c     34
3   sh    b     18
```

How can I do that in R? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using `subset` :

```
subset(df, city == 'bj' & type %in% c('a', 'c') | city == 'sh' & type == 'b')

#  city type count
#0   bj    a    10
#1   bj    a    23
#3   bj    c    34
#5   sh    b    18
```

Or `filter` in `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(city == 'bj' & type %in% c('a', 'c') | 
         city == 'sh' & type == 'b')
```

Answer (score 1):

For a base R option, you could subset using direct bracket notation:

```
df[(df$city == "bj" & df$type %in% c("a", "c")) |
   (df$city == "sh" & df$type == "b"), ]

  city type count
1   bj    a    10
2   bj    a    23
4   bj    c    34
6   sh    b    18
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(city=c("bj", "bj", "bj", "bj", "sh", "sh", "sh", "sh", "sh" ),
                 type=c("a", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "c", "a"),
                 count=c(10, 23, 12, 34, 17, 18, 25, 13, 12), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```